# Twig templating conditional pattern loop

Tags: javascript, loops, twig, conditional-statements

I have a feeling that this will be a very simple solution but I just can't wrap my head around it right now. I'm building a Craft CMS template with Twig and wanted to layout some elements (gallery image blocks) in a specific pattern. Similar to this example. [example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ0hx.jpg)

As I loop through each of my elements I want to display them appropriately, small and large. sm, sm, lg, lg, sm, sm, sm, sm, lg, lg... and so on.

I know I can obviously preform a loop like this

```
{% if loop.index is even %}
...
{% endif %}
```

or like this one for a result of [sm, sm, lg, sm, sm lg]

```
{% if loop.index is divisible by(3) %}
...
{% endif %}
```

but my pattern is a little more complicated.

Thanks, for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure what pattern you're trying to capture here.

Comment: Yes, please clarify EXACTLY what you might need!

Comment: I basically want to trigger "true" the first two times, then "false" two times, then "true" four times and so on (like the pattern above).

Comment: Sorry, it's a little hard to visualize in the photo, because it will repeat, giving me four small images in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired pattern is `sm sm lg` printing normally, then reversed, then normally...

`sm sm lg
lg sm sm
sm sm lg
...`

You can create a `macro` (a [function in Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html)) that outputs this pattern:

```
{% macro printPattern(reverse = false) %} {# the function AKA macro signature #}
    {% set sm = 'a small image' %} {# Make this an <img> tag. #}
    {% set lg = 'a large image' %}
    {% set pattern = (reverse) ? [lg, sm, sm] : [sm, sm, lg] %}

    {% for n in pattern %}{{ n }} {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{# If you wanted to use the macro in the same file you must include: #}
{% import from _self as helper %}

{# Then call the macro: #}
{{ helper.printPattern(false) }}
{{ helper.printPattern(true) }}
{{ helper.printPattern() }} {# This does the same as helper.printPattern(false) #}
{# because we set a default value for the passed-in variable in the macro's signature. #}
```

[Example](https://twigfiddle.com/xld36e)

---

## Special note:

I used the `ternary` operator `?` on this line:

`{% set pattern = (reverse) ? [lg, sm, sm] : [sm, sm, lg] %}`

(Recall that `reverse` is a `boolean` value, i.e. `true` or `false`).

That line is equivalent to:

```
{% if reverse %}
    {% set pattern = [sm, sm, lg] %}
{% else %}
    {% set pattern = [lg, sm, sm] %}
{% endif %}
```

The [Ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) is very handy for conditionally assigning some data to a variable.

Comment: Okay, i've been playing around with your code and I think I'm on the right page but I'm a little lost when it comes to implementing varibles into the patterns. This is what I have.

https://twigfiddle.com/xld36e

At what point do I look over a set of three variables to implement into the pattern?

Comment: @TimCook, that link is pointing to my example. Do you have a save?

Comment: I thought I updated that, try twigfiddle.com/xld36e/2

Comment: Here's another reworked version that works perfect for me but I'm sure it can be simplified better. https://twigfiddle.com/xld36e/3